# Can't show/print int in if-else statement

Tags: haskell

In the following code I am trying to show the result of factorial, which is an integer. I got the following error message, I am wondering what happened and why.   Thanks!

```
factorial2 0 = 1
factorial2 n = n * factorial2 (n-1)

main = do putStrLn "What is 5! ?"
        x <- readLn
        if x == factorial2 5
            then putStrLn "Right" 
            -- else print factorial2 5  -- why can't pass here
            -- else show factorial2 5  -- why can't pass here
            else putStrLn "Wrong"  -- this can pass, no problem

-- Factorial.hs:10:20:
--     Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> IO ()’
--                 with actual type ‘IO ()’
--     The function ‘print’ is applied to two arguments,
--     but its type ‘(a0 -> a0) -> IO ()’ has only one
--     In the expression: print factorial2 5
--     In a stmt of a 'do' block:
--       if x == factorial2 5 then putStrLn "Right" else print factorial2 5
-- Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 3):

Haskell function application is left associative. What that means is that when you call `print factorial2 5` haskell interprets it as you passing 2 arguments to print: `factorial2` and `5`, but print only takes one argument. If your code was another language it would be equivalent to: `print(factorial2, 5)`.

The reason `show factorial2 5` doesn't work is because everything in your do block is required to return an IO() but `show factorial2 5` returns a string.

Simply `print (factorial2 5)` would work so that haskell knows you want to pass the result of `factorial2 5` to `print`.

Comment: I would say that Haskell (function application) is *left* associative: `print factorial2 5` is the same as `(print factorial2) 5`.

Comment: @DavidYoung thanks you are totally right, got my left and right mixed up lol. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

The functions *show* has the type : `a -> String`.
So it takes one argument and converts it to a string.

In your line

```
 else show factorial2 5  -- why can't pass here
```

you give **two** arguments, namely *factorial2* and *5*.

You have to give one argument to the function *show*, in your case the result of `factorial2 5` Therefore you have to put *factorial2 5* into parenthesis:

```
 else show (factorial2 5)
```

Often you will see the *$* operator:

```
 else show $ factorial2 5
```

It allows you to save parenthesis.